# use Object.assign() in each object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I don't know why in my result for some items, the value is wrong.

```
var myArray = [{
    item: "my apple 1",
    value: 1
}, {
    item: "my carrot",
    value: 2
}, {
    item: "my banana",
    value: 3
}, {
    item: "my potatoe",
    value: 4
}, {
    item: "my apple 2",
    value: 0
}];


var MyArrayDefinition = [{
    item: "my apple 1",
    color: "red",
    group: "fruit",
    score: 1
}, {
    item: "my carrot",
    color: "orange",
    group: "vegetable",
    score: 0
}, {
    item: "my banana",
    color: "yellow",
    group: "fruit",
    score: 1
}, {
    item: "my apple 2",
    color: "red",
    group: "fruit",
    score: 0
}, {
    item: "my potatoe",
    color: "yellow",
    group: "vegetable",
    score: 0
}, ]
```

this is my function but the result is strange for the item "my apple 2"

```
    var result = [];
    myArray.forEach((itm, i) => {
    result.push(Object.assign({}, itm, MyArrayDefinition[i]));
```

I'd like

```
[{
item: "my apple 1",
color: "red",
group: "fruit",
score: 1,
value: 1
}, {
item: "my carrot",
color: "orange",
group: "vegetable",
score: 0,
value: 2
}, {
item: "my banana",
color: "yellow",
group: "fruit",
score: 1,
value: 3
}, {
item: "my apple 2",
color: "red",
group: "fruit",
score: 0,
value: 0
}, {
item: "my potatoe",
color: "yellow",
group: "vegetable",
score: 0,
value: 4
}];
```

Comment: 'the result is strange' - please define *strange* and / or show the output that it gives you

Comment: The order of your potato and apple aren't matched in both arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only works if the both arrays have the exact same order and length. To have it flexible, use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and match the second object by item property.

```js
const myArray = [{item:"my apple 1", value:1},{item:"my carrot", value:2},{item:"my banana", value:3},{item:"my potatoe", value:4},{item:"my apple 2", value:0}];
const MyArrayDefinition = [{item:"my apple 1", color:"red", group:"fruit", score:1},{item:"my carrot", color:"orange", group:"vegetable", score:0},{item:"my banana", color:"yellow", group:"fruit", score:1},{item:"my apple 2", color:"red", group:"fruit", score:0},{item:"my potatoe", color:"yellow", group:"vegetable", score:0},]

const combined = myArray.map(e => Object.assign(e, MyArrayDefinition.find(x => x.item === e.item)));
console.log(combined);
```

If both arrays are huge, consider to index the MyArrayDefinition first:

```js
const myArray = [{item:"my apple 1", value:1},{item:"my carrot", value:2},{item:"my banana", value:3},{item:"my potatoe", value:4},{item:"my apple 2", value:0}];
const MyArrayDefinition = [{item:"my apple 1", color:"red", group:"fruit", score:1},{item:"my carrot", color:"orange", group:"vegetable", score:0},{item:"my banana", color:"yellow", group:"fruit", score:1},{item:"my apple 2", color:"red", group:"fruit", score:0},{item:"my potatoe", color:"yellow", group:"vegetable", score:0},]


const indices = MyArrayDefinition.map((e) => e.item);
const comb = myArray.map(e => Object.assign(e, MyArrayDefinition[indices.indexOf(e.item)]));
console.log(comb);
```

It seems to be a bit faster even for the small arrays, so you should benefit from it for a real world scenario. [Check performance here](https://jsperf.com/tttfdasfasdf/1)

Answer (score 1):

Your merge snippet assumes arrays that have matching items. I.e.: the index of `my apple 2` has to be the same in both `myArray` and `MyArrayDefinition`.

If you want to support varying sets and still correctly merge, you could create a function that works a bit like a `groupBy`. Two important steps in your logic are:

1. What makes two objects suitable for merging?
   *In your case:*  `(a, b) => a.item === b.item`
2. How do we merge two objects?
   *In your case:* (`a, b) => Object.assign({}, a, b})`

Now, we can (naively) reduce the `myArray` without worrying about the order:

```js
var myArray=[{item:"my apple 1",value:1},{item:"my carrot",value:2},{item:"my banana",value:3},{item:"my potatoe",value:4},{item:"my apple 2",value:0}];
var MyArrayDefinition = [{ item: "my apple 1", color: "red", group: "fruit", score: 1 }, { item: "my carrot", color: "orange", group: "vegetable", score: 0 }, { item: "my banana", color: "yellow", group: "fruit", score: 1 }, { item: "my apple 2", color: "red", group: "fruit", score: 0 }, { item: "my potatoe", color: "yellow", group: "vegetable", score: 0 } ];

var merged = myArray.map(
  (x) => {
    const pair = MyArrayDefinition.find(y => x.item === y.item);
    return (Object.assign({}, x, pair || {}));
  });
  
console.log(merged);
```

Note that this function is still very inefficient, because it uses `find` in every loop. If you need performance, you can index your items by `item` key first.

Answer (score -1):

```
var result = [];
myArray.forEach((itm, i) => {
result.push(Object.assign({}, itm, MyArrayDefinition[i]));
```

In the above line , you just need to replace the itm and MyArrayDefinition[i] in the Object.assign method.

like this ,

```
evar result = [];
myArray.forEach((itm, i) => {
result.push(Object.assign({}, MyArrayDefinition[i],itm));
```